# Kubernetes unable to retrieve logs

Tags: kubernetes

I have kubeadm cluster deployed in CentOS VM. while trying to deploy `ingress controller` following [github](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/deploy/README.md) i noticed that i'm unable to see logs:

```
kubectl logs -n ingress-nginx nginx-ingress-controller-697f7c6ddb-x9xkh --previous

Error from server: Get https://192.168.56.34:10250/containerLogs/ingress-nginx/nginx-ingress-controller-697f7c6ddb-x9xkh/nginx-ingress-controller?previous=true: dial tcp 192.168.56.34:10250: getsockopt: connection timed out
```

In 192.168.56.34 (node1) netstat returns:

```
tcp6       0      0 :::10250                :::*                    LISTEN      1068/kubelet
```

In fact i'm unable to see any logs despite the status of the pod.

I disabled both the `firewalld` and  `SELinux`.

I used `proxy` to enable kubernertes to download images, now i removed the proxy.

When navigating to the url in the error above i get `Forbidden (user=system:anonymous, verb=get, resource=nodes, subresource=proxy)`

I'm also able to fetch my nodes:

```
kubectl get node
NAME         STATUS     ROLES     AGE       VERSION
k8s-master   Ready      master    32d       v1.9.3
k8s-node1    Ready      <none>    30d       v1.9.3
k8s-node2    NotReady   <none>    32d       v1.9.3
```

Comment: `k8s-node2    NotReady` should not appear, and you should find out why it is unhappy; `kubectl get nodes -o wide` will also output the node's IP address, in case it happens to be 192.168.56.34

Answer (score 2):

> getsockopt: connection timed out

Is 99.99999% a firewall issue. If it was "connection refused" then showing the output of netstat would be meaningful, but (as you can see) `kubelet` is listening on that port just fine -- it's the networking configuration between the machine that is running `kubectl` and "192.168.56.34" that is incorrectly configured to allow traffic.

The apiserver expects that everyone who would want to view logs (or use `kubectl exec`) can reach that port on every Node in the cluster; so be sure you don't just fix the firewall rule(s) for that one Node -- fix it for all of them.

Comment: I disabled both the `firewalld` and  `SELinux`

Comment: SELinux is not a firewall, so disabling it won't help. And I actually wouldn't guess that it is a problem with the machine itself - those rules are usually caused by an issue between the `kubectl` machine and the node. But can you run this command from the master and see if it also times out: `curl -v https://192.168.56.34:10250/containerLogs`

Comment: curl: (7) Failed connect to 192.168.56.34:10250; Connection timed out

Comment: in that case, we're going to need more info about your nodes, so either update the question or post a pastebin containing the output of `kubectl describe nodes`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, problem was in my network, my node didn't have the same `ip mask` as the master, the ability of the master to list the nodes with status `ready` made me ignore the networking, i really apreciate your help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This message is from the **apiserver** running on your master. The command `kubectl logs`, running on your local machine, fetches logs via the apiserver. So the error message reveals a firewall misconfiguration **between the master and the node(s)** (port 10250)

Comment: I disabled both the `firewalld` and  `SELinux`